# How to detect the redirect of a URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I'm getting back a URL that isn't the final URL, it's just a redirect, so I need to determine the URL address of the final URL.  I'm working with NSURLSession but can't quite figure it out, in a playground the below code gives me the URL, but I'm not sure how to call this function, i.e. what params to pass in?

```
 func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        print(response.URL) 

        completionHandler(nil)
    }
```

EDIT:  I'm using NSURLConnection and Swift so I'd like to find a solution using the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inspecting `response.URL`, which is incorrect. You should inspect `request.URL` instead. In this context `request` is a new URL Request object that represents the request for the redirected URL.

Comment: Thanks Aaron but if I'm trying to test ```let testURL = "www.somewebsite.com" ``` what params do I pass into my URLSession function for session, task, etc?

Comment: Never mind, I understand now...it's a delegate method.  Wasn't thinking!

Comment: @GarySabo Would you mind sharing the delegate method that work for you? I'm trying to do the same thing here. Thanks.